# Multiple maps not working for Google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have some jquery (below) with creates multiple maps on window load. However there is some strange behaviour with the maps, but no errors.

The problem is when the maps load they all have the same location on the map, even when multiple different lng and lats are set.

Below is the the code that create the map and some sample html of one of the maps's boxes.

The strange thing is that the maps have the same locations but there are not errors. Has anyone experienced this before or know why it's happening.

Cheers.

Js: (assume this is called onloand and some blank global arrays are set.)

```
var maps_boxes = {
    initialise: function() {
        $('.a_map').each(function(index) {
            var map_box = $(this);
            var map_id = map_box.find('.the_map').attr('id');
            var lat = map_box.find('.lat').val();
            var lng = map_box.find('.lat').val();

            lat_lngs[index] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);          

            options[index] = {
              zoom: 4,
              center: lat_lngs[index],
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            maps[index] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(map_id), options[index]);

        });
    }
};
```

Sample html of one map:

```
<div class="a_map">
  <form class="map_data" >
    lng:<input class="lng" type="text" value="0" /><br />
    lat:<input class="lat" type="text" value="10" />
  </form>
  <div id="map_xxxxx" class="the_map" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same code you posted, you are getting same value for both the latitude and longitude:

```
    var lat = map_box.find('.lat').val();
    var lng = map_box.find('.lat').val();
```

I tried initializing 2 different maps on same page it is working fine.